# Conditions under which EFLAGS flags are set in x86/x64

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, eflags

I would like to know what are the conditions under which the basic EFLAGS flags (CF, ZF, OF, SF...) are set. I have looked into the Intel x86 instruction manual, and [this website](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html) that is well done, but without success. I managed to find the conditions for the conditional jumps (for example, a JLE is taken if (SF != OF) or (ZF == 1)), but not regarding the flags themselves.

Regarding ZF, it is the easiest one, as it is only needed to check if the result is zero. For SF, I assume that one have to check if the most significant bit of the result is zero or one. But for the others, I am unsure. Additionally, are those conditions the same across all x86 instructions manipulating those flags, or do an ADD and a CMP will set their flags under different equations?

Answer (score 2):

The [intel SDM](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html) does answer your question on Volume 1 - 3.4.3 EFLAGS Register.

Partly quoting the doc:

> 3.4.3.1 Status Flags
>
> The status flags (bits 0, 2, 4, 6, 7, and 11) of the EFLAGS register indicate the results of arithmetic instructions,
> such as the ADD, SUB, MUL, and DIV instructions. The status flag functions are:
>
> - CF (bit 0) Carry flag — Set if an arithmetic operation generates a carry or a borrow out of the most-
>   significant bit of the result; cleared otherwise. This flag indicates an overflow condition for
>   unsigned-integer arithmetic. It is also used in multiple-precision arithmetic.
> - PF (bit 2) Parity flag — Set if the least-significant byte of the result contains an even number of 1 bits;
>   cleared otherwise.
> - AF (bit 4) Auxiliary Carry flag — Set if an arithmetic operation generates a carry or a borrow out of bit
>   3 of the result; cleared otherwise. This flag is used in binary-coded decimal (BCD) arithmetic.
> - ZF (bit 6) Zero flag — Set if the result is zero; cleared otherwise.
>
> [...]

That is not the most in-depth source you'll find on the subject, as it won't cover errata for various x86 implementations (and there's a ton of those...) but it is certainly the best to get you started.

Happy hacking ;)

Comment: Very few errata are related to basic functionality like setting FLAGS.  Some instructions (like MUL and DIV) don't set most FLAGS this way, though (e.g. [ZF not set as a result of MUL instruction in assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25905651)).  Very strange of Intel to mention those as instructions that set flags in a normal way like ADD/SUB, / XOR/OR/AND, or shifts.  (Set "according to the result").  http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html lists flags modified and well-defined vs. undefined for every form (opcode) of every instruction.

Comment: The complete version of this bullet list quote appears in [What does "set according to the result" mean in Intel's SDM manuals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40478386) (where it's a good answer, because it does define what it means when instructions like `adc` say "The OF, SF, ZF, AF, CF, and PF flags are set according to the result." (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/adc#flags-affected - every instruction has a Flags Affected section in the manual.)